# Can't properly force a component on-screen with scrollComponentToVisible

Tags: codenameone

On a given form, we replace one component with another.

The original component is a series of TextFields, and the new form is some informational text and a button. We hide the first one, and show the second one (the UI designer has both Containers within the form).

I tried using `scrollRectToVisible` with various values but it didn't seem to make any difference with the scrolling.

```
 continueButtonContainer.setHidden(false);
 f.forceRevalidate();
 Button continueButton = 
     (Button)StateMachine.GetInstance().findByName("ButtonContinue", f);
 f.scrollComponentToVisible(continueButtonContainer);
 f.scrollComponentToVisible(continueButton);
```

I'm expecting the continue button to be near the top of the screen.

If the screen was scrolled before displaying the continue button, the button ends up right at the bottom of the screen (it was below the bottom of the screen before I put in the `scrollComponentToVisible` line(s).

After the user scrolls the screen, the button goes up to where it needs to be, and stays there.

If the screen is not scrolled, the button appears where it should be.

I know I can probably add some invisible containers underneath the button and force them onto the screen, but I would rather have a slightly more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this. First you are using `forceRevalidate` which should be used in very rare cases.

Second it seems that you are invoking this on a `Form`, this is a bit misleading. While it seems that:

```
f.add(myCmp);
```

Adds a component to the form it is really a synonym to:

```
f.getContentPane().add(myCmp);
```

That's important because you need to invoke the `scrollComponentToVisible` on the scrollable container which will actually do the work and ideally be the direct parent of said component. I'm assuming it's the content pane in your case but it depends on layout etc.

The last part is letting the layout do its job. If you are invoking this before the form is showing this might not work. Notice that doing it after a call to `show` is meaningless as the form might take time with transitions. You can use a show listener or override the `laidOut` callback method to perform things like this.